# Django query clause be included if data exist else be excluded

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I have a query which I want to perform. If the query variable has some things in them the query should be presented. But if it does not have anything inside of them then it should be left blank

```
    Modelname.objects.raw("select * from tab1, tab2, tab3 where
    tab1.id=tab1.tb2_id and tab3.id=tab1.tb3_id and
    CASE %s
        WHEN None
            THEN    #This place is basically empty
        ELSE tab1.name=%s
    END
    and 
    CASE %s
        WHEN 0
            THEN #This place is also basically empty
        ELSE tab1.year=%s 
    END", [user_name,user_name,digit,digit])
```

Comment: Is there a good reason you use raw query instead of ORM?

Comment: @ariaman5 I have tried using ORM but i want to link three models/tables which are not linked but have same data. that is why I am using raw instead of ORM